# Как работает импортированный модуль JS?

Tags: javascript, функции, импорт, export, модули

Я создал, что-то на подобие генератора удобных паролей. Пароли не отличаются надежностью. Главное, чтобы можно было легко запомнить.

На данный момент у меня стоит задача разделения одного js файла на два. В одном из которых будет обработчик и глобальные переменные полученные из index.html, а в другом сама функция.

Если открыть консоль разработчика, видны ошибки:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: numbers is not defined
- at HTMLButtonElement.generatePass (main.js:5)
- at window.onload (app.js:19)

Он не видит переменную numbers, пытается найти ее в main.js, почему так? А еще ругается на window.onload тоже не знаю почему..
Наиболее вероятно, я неправильно делаю импорт или экспорт. Но я надеюсь логику того, что я пытаюсь сделать, вы поняли. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Для модуля, в примере, это не глобальные переменные и он их не видит.

И глобальные определять не стоит никогда, если в этом нет необходимости.

Файл настроек './setting.js'

```js
export const numbers = [1, 2, 3]
export const punctuation = ['!']
```

Файл функции генератора './generate.js'

```js
// Импортируем все настройки или передаем их аргументами
import * as setting from './setting.js'

function generate() {
  console.log(setting.numbers)
  console.log(setting.punctuation)
}
export {
  generate
}
```

Файл запуска './main.js' - его и импортируем в документ.

```js
import { generate } from './generate.js'

generate()
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// [ '!' ]
```